# Использование слова "впрочем"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Можно ли использовать слово "впрочем" в таком тексте: "Знает ли он этого человека? Я предполагаю, что нет (в противном случае он вёл бы себя более уверенно). Впрочем, знает или нет ─ неважно"?
И вообще: можно узнать все случаи, когда можно употреблять слово "впрочем"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знает ли он этого человека? Я предполагаю, что нет (в противном случае он вёл бы себя более уверенно). **Впрочем,** знает или нет ─ неважно.

Впрочем ─ интересное слово, оно происходит от  прилагательного **"прочий"** со значением "**остальной**, другой", которое этимологически восходит к существительному **"прок"** (остаток).

От слова "прочий" образуются два вводных слова: **впрочем  и между прочим** (= кстати говоря, к слову сказать). Слово "впрочем"   обозначает переход к **другой** мысли (**к прочему**), которая выражает **сомнение, колебание и может отличаться**  от сказанного ранее: Будешь пить чай? ─ Нет, впрочем, налей!

И вот это слово может быть **вводным словом  или присоединительным союзом.**

**Из словаря:**

**ВПРОЧЕМ.** I. **союз.** (присоединяет предл. или его часть, ограничивающие и уточняющие смысл предшествующего). Однако; тем не менее; всё же. Я знаю его тайну, впрочем не я один.  II. **вводн. сл.** Выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение. Сделайте вечерний чай и, пожалуйста, без вина и без закусок; впрочем, я сама всё устрою.

**В то же время в "Трудных случаях русской пунктуации" обособление делается в обоих случаях** (для союза и для вводного слова), что вполне объяснимо, так как различать эти варианты  сложно и не имеет смысла: **выполняя функцию союза, вводное слово сохраняет и статус вводности.**

**Пример:** Город Бельск очень похож на все уездные города; впрочем, он выгодно отличается от своих собратий удивительною чистотою улиц.

Запятая в этом предложении (в большинстве приводимых текстов) ставится, и очень к месту. Структура предложения соответствует БСП, вводное слово обособляется в начале второй части  предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза читается нормально. Исходите из того, что это союз, он соответствует по значению таким выражениям, как *однако, всё-таки, тем не менее*. Отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения. Подробнее смотрите [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_107) и [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC).

Comment: "[Город Бельск] очень похож на все уездные города; **впрочем он выгодно отличается** от своих собратий удивительною чистотою улиц".  — Гаршин, Медведи. Не отделяется.

Comment: Aer, а почему Вы считаете, что у Гаршина запятой в этом предложении не было?

Comment: Запятая есть: https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8_(%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Comment: @slava1947 я не считаю, а привожу цитату из Малого академического словаря (я также проверил в бумажном экземпляре — всё так). Надо смотреть либо рукопись (не помню, сжег ли он ее), либо, что лучше, старые издания. МАС, несомненно, более авторитетный источник, чем Вики, однако и в нем могут быть опечатки — нужно проверять.

Answer (score 1):

Из МАС:

> впро́чем.
>
> 1. *противительный союз.* Присоединяет предложение (или его часть), ограничивающее высказанную мысль, положение; соответствует по значению словам: однако, тем не менее, всё же.
>      [Город Бельск] очень похож на все уездные города; впрочем он выгодно отличается от своих собратий удивительною чистотою улиц. Гаршин, Медведи.
> 2. *в знач. вводн. сл.* Выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение.
>      [Степка:] Печку-то затопить? [Софья:] Не нужно… Впрочем — затопи. М. Горький, Зыковы. — Вот вы улыбаетесь. А впрочем, может быть, я говорю и не то, что надо. Катаев, Короленко.

В приведенном вами контексте слово *впрочем* выглядит вполне уместно.

Comment: У Гаршина запятая после слова "впрочем" :https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8_(%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Comment: @М_Г см. комментарий к вашему ответу.